# Function with Generic object as parameter

Tags: android, function, generics, methods, kotlin

How to create method that takes generic object as parameter?
Like object of class `Apple` or `Cycle`. I don't want to downcast it from `Any`.

```
fun putObject(y: <T> /*and even only "T"*/) {
}
```

Comment: you can create like `fun <T> putObject(y: T /*and even only "T"*/) {}` like this

Comment: Thank you........

Comment: Refer to Kotlin generics docs: [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-functions):

> Not only classes can have type parameters. Functions can, too. Type parameters are placed before the name of the function:
>
> ```
> fun <T> singletonList(item: T): List<T> {
>      // ...
> }
> ```

You have to declare that `T` is a type parameter. You have to do it before the name of the function (like you would in Java). Rewriting your code as follows works:

```
fun <T> putObject(y: T) {
    // ...
}
```